# Does negative third derivative imply negative first derivative?

Tags: calculus, control-theory

Does negative third derivative imply negative first derivative? For a system, the negative of the derivative of the Lyapunov function means the system is stable. How about the negative third derivative?

Answer (score 0):

No, consider $f(x) = x-x^3$ at $x=0$.

$f'(0) = 1 > 0$, while $f'''(0) = -6 < 0$.

Perhaps you are assuming additional contraints?

Comment: The function itself is positive defined coz it represent energy.

Comment: I think it is true that if $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is defined everywhere and sufficiently continuously differentiable, then $f'''<0$ everywhere implies $f'<0$ somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Consider $f(x) = x^4 - 4x^3 + 5x^2 + 1$.  This function is everywhere positive: $f > 0$.

Also, $f' > 0$ on $(0,\infty)$ and $f''' < 0$ on $(-\infty, 1)$.

This means that on the interval $(0,1)$ we have both $f''' < 0$ and $f' > 0$.